# How to remove the fragments so it wont appear in the next activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, fragment, main-activity

So i've just started doing some android programing, and I'm already stuck! My problem is; I want want my fragment, from MainActivity, to NOT be a part of my new Activity. I want the activity to be all blank, the fragment from MainActivity should be gone, buuut it's not.

The content from the "fragmentz" xml document, which is "linked" in the Fragment Class. Should NOT appear in the second Activity... Where in the SecondActivity have I associated it with the Fragment Class? This is getting frustrating :D

So here is my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


FragmentManager manager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    manager= getSupportFragmentManager();

    ArticleFragment frag = new ArticleFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragmentet,frag,"tagg");
    transaction.commit();

    // here the Fragment should be added to my MainActiviy
}




public void WalkForward(View view)
{


    ArticleFragment frag = (ArticleFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag("tagg");
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    transaction.remove(frag);
    transaction.commit(); 
    // Here, the fragment should disappear before the new activity start


    Intent intenten = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intenten);
    // Start new activity


    finish();
    // I've tried this finish method, and also onDestroy and so on... But that work either. I thought the Fragments should 
    // disappear with its activity?

}






@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

My Fragment Class:

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {

public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    Log.d("Fraggment", "onAttach");
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // #17 Android FragmentTransaction Part 2: Android Application Development Development [HD 1080p]
}

public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
    Log.d("Fraggment", "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentz, container, false);
}


public void onActivityCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
    Log.d("Fraggment", "onActivityCreated");
    super.onActivityCreated(saveInstanceState);

}

public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("Fraggment", "onPause");

}

public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("Fraggment", "onStop");


}

public void onDestroyView()
{
    super.onDestroyView();
    Log.d("Fraggment", "onDestroyView");


}

public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("Fraggment", "onDestroy");


}


public void onDetach()
{
    super.onDetach();
    Log.d("Fraggment", "onDetach");


}
```

And my Second Activity Class:

```
public class SecondActivity extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

I hope you understand what I mean :P  Is there anything I can do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
```

from your Second Activity. And why are you extending MainActivity? Some Reason?

Comment: Yeah, that did it. After i removed the extending MainActivity (which I've no idea why it was there xD) it worked. Thanks! :)

Comment: Lol. It happens. Anyway your problem is fixed. I think you might have copy pasted some code and forgot to remove this.